# does cloud run support gsutil command for nodejs application?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I created an application in which hitting PUT API stores the request body in a file and that file is stored inside a GCP bucket via a gsutil command:

`` exec(`gsutil -m cp -r  ./ddr_requests_${date.getFullYear()}_${month}_${day}_${hour}:${minutes}.json  gs://gibberish/${date.getFullYear()}-${month}-${day}/`, (err, stdout, stderr) => { if (err) { console.log('Error'); return; } ``

This seems to work fine when application is tested locally.... file gets created and also gets stored inside a GCP bucket..but when I deploy the application on Cloud Run, it does not work at all ... nor do I see any error in logs.

Is this a case of Cloud Run not supporting gsutil command?... Please help

Comment: Do you have errors in the logs? maybe credential issues. Are you also sure that gsutil is installed in your container? Finally, you can also implement yourselves the same process with the Cloud Storage APIs and/or client libraries

Comment: Calling gsutil from a nodejs application in cloud run really doesn't make any sense, have a look at the GCS node client instead: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object , this code sample does exactly the same thing as that copy

Comment: @somethingsomething - thanks for your inputs... it helped me a lot to progress...but I landed up in another problem .... hitting PUT API locally via Postman creates a file and that gets uploaded to the bucket....but after deploying the application to Cloud Run doesn't upload the file after hitting the API via Postman. I even tried moving the file upload codebase inside the PUT block but no luck...

Comment: If something works locally but not in cloud run that's quite likely a permission or config issue. The error should help you try figure it out (and if you aren't seeing errors in the logs you are probably doing something wrong in your code). Nobody but yourself will be able to help you without the error and the code provided.